# ID from the database to the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am starting my game with CodeIgniter and I have a problem - I would like to download the ID - of the product from the database so that it will be passed to the URL address:

I managed to do something like this:

```
http://localhost/seo2/api/admin/domains/notes/{{domainID}}
```

I would like something like this:

```
http://localhost/seo2/api/admin/domains/{{domainID}}/notes
```

My model -notes-model.php

```
class notes_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get( $id = false)
    {
        if ( $id == false ) {
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->result();
        }
        else{
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->row();
        }
        return $q;
    }

    public function update($note)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $note['id'] );
        $this->db->update('notes', $note);
    }

    public function create($note)
    {

        $this->db->insert('notes', $note);

    }

    public function delete($note)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $note['id'] );
        $this->db->delete('notes');
    }

    public function get_by_domain_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id_domain_rel', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('notes');
        $q = $q->result();

        return $q;
    }

}
```

My controller notes.php:

```
class notes extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $post = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $_POST = json_decode($post,true);
        $this->load->model('admin/notes_model');
    }


    public function get($id = false)
    {
        $result = $this->notes_model->get($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }



    public function update()
    {
        $note = $this->input->post('note');
        $this->notes_model->update($note);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $note = $this->input->post('note');
        $this->notes_model->create($note);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $note = $this->input->post('note');
        $this->notes_model->delete($note);
    }
}
```

My model domains_model.php:

```
class domains_model extends CI_Model {


    public function get( $id = false)
    {
        if ( $id == false ) {
            $q = $this->db->get('domains');
            $q = $q->result();
        }
        else{
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $q = $this->db->get('domains');
            $q = $q->row();
        }
        return $q;
    }

    public function update($domain)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $domain['id'] );
        $this->db->update('domains', $domain);
    }

    public function create($domain)
    {
        $this->db->insert('domains', $domain);
    }

    public function delete($domain)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $domain['id'] );
        $this->db->delete('domains');
    }

}
```

My controller domains.php

```
class domains extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $post = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $_POST = json_decode($post,true);
        $this->load->model('admin/domains_model');
    }

    public function get($id = false)
    {
        $result = $this->domains_model->get($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $domain = $this->input->post('domain');
        $this->domains_model->update($domain);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $domain = $this->input->post('domain');
        $this->domains_model->create($domain);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $domain = $this->input->post('domain');
        $this->domains_model->delete($domain);
    }

    public function notes($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('admin/notes_model');
        $result = $this->notes_model->get_by_domain_id($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what is exactly you are asking about.Have you tried any solutions for your question? place the code of your failed attempts and the result/errors you received

Comment: do you want to pass id in URL?

Comment: @suresh Yes, the URL was generated in the way I showed above. 
 - look URL - https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/